Akeida and the laws of Noach
Wasn't the episode of the Akeidat Yitzchak wrong, in terms of valuing human life?
We are taught that before Matan Torah, all the world was under the jurisdiction of the Noachide laws.
Avraham Avinu, would have most likely told himself that this is wrong but he still proceeded with it as much as he could.
Then, was the episode of Akeida considered attempted murder, according to the laws of Noach?

I have heard that Abraham's lack of argument over the matter was a shortcoming. In contrast, Moshe refused God's offer to destroy the Jews and start a nation from him.

How could a direct command from G-d be "wrong"?

@shmosel it could easily be a test like with Moses.

Technically, the Torah puts the value of human life below the value of submission to God, who presents himself to the Israelites as jealous and vengeful. He also kills more people in the Torah than anybody else.
